# How to solve "cannot coerce class to data.frame?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, training-data, supervised-learning

Problems occur in Line 20: `x3 <- lm(Salary ~ ...`

> Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : cannot coerce class ‘c("train", "train.formula")’ to a data.frame

How to solve?

```
attach(Hitters)
Hitters

library(caret)
set.seed(123)
# Define training control
set.seed(123) 
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
# Train the model
x2 <- train(Salary ~., data = x, method = "lm",
               trControl = train.control)
# Summarize the results
print(x)
x3 <- lm(Salary ~ poly(AtBat,3) + poly(Hits,3) + poly(Walks,3) + poly(CRuns,3) + poly(CWalks,3) + poly(PutOuts,3), data = x2)
summary(x3)
MSE = mean(x3$residuals^2)
print("Mean Squared Error: ")
print(MSE)
```

Comment: Hard to say. You do not indicate where `Hitters` comes from (there are multiple versions on R). You do not define `x`. But most likely it is your attempt to use `x2` as a data frame in the call to `lm`. The manual page for `train` indicates that it returns "a list of class `train`" which is not a data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

First, as @dcarlson already mentioned, you should define x.
Second, x3 does not return a data frame.
If you run

```
str(x2)
```

you'll see that all the elements you're using in the lm function are part of a data frame called trainingData. 
So if you intend to use the lm function, use that as your data source in the lm function, **NOT** x2.
I've rewritten your code below.

PS I'm far from a R expert so if someone wants to shoot at this answer, go ahead, I'm always willing to learn ;)

```
attach(Hitters)
Hitters

library(caret)
set.seed(123)

# Define training control
set.seed(123) 
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)

# Train the model
x2 <- train(Salary ~., data = x, method = "lm", trControl = train.control)

# Summarize the results
print(x2)
# str(x2) # $trainingData data.frame

x2$trainingData[["AtBat"]]
m <- x2$trainingData

x3 <- lm(Salary ~ poly(AtBat,3) + poly(Hits,3) + poly(Walks,3) + poly(CRuns,3) + poly(CWalks,3) + poly(PutOuts,3), data = m)
summary(x3)
MSE = mean(x3$residuals^2)
cat("Mean Squared Error: ", MSE) # use cat to concatenate text and variable value in one line
```